# Case Statement for SSRS

Tags: sql, case

I have a case statement in my where clause and what I am attempting to do is make this report where you can search by the Claim ID, Member ID, or the Provider ID. The issue is that the Member ID and Provider ID are both located in the same field which is the Folder_ID but labeled differently with the Folder_Type.

When I use the case statement the way it is currently written I don't get any results. When I try to use an OR instead of AND, I return too much. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
    SELECT
    xfl.xml_file_id                              
    , dh.document_id                             
    , dh.document_description                    
    , dh.document_date                           
    , MAX(CASE WHEN xfi.FOLDER_TYPE_ID = '19' THEN xfi.folder_id ELSE null  END) AS memberID
    , MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300' THEN LEFT(xfi.folder_id, LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5) ELSE NULL END) AS providerid
    , xfl.xml_file_name                     
    , dp.document_file_path                 

       FROM 
       reporting.[FacetsRunout].[XML_FILE_LIST]              
       xfl 
       JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Folder_ID]                 
       xfi      ON xfi.XML_FILE_ID = XFL.XML_FILE_ID
       LEFT JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Document_Page]       dp       
       ON dp.XML_FILE_ID = xfl.XML_FILE_ID
       JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Document_Header]           
       dh       ON dh.XML_FILE_ID = xfl.XML_FILE_ID

      WHERE
     dh.document_id LIKE '%'+@ClaimID+'%'
     AND CASE WHEN xfi.FOLDER_TYPE_ID = '19' THEN xfi.folder_id ELSE null  
     END LIKE '%'+@MemberID+'%'
     AND CASE WHEN RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300' THEN 
     LEFT(xfi.folder_id, LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5) ELSE NULL END LIKE 
     '%'+@ProviderID+'%'

    GROUP BY 
     xfl.xml_file_id                                
     , dh.document_id                           
     , dh.document_description                  
     , dh.document_date                 
     , xfl.xml_file_name                    
     , dp.document_file_path
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your CASE statements use NULL if your field doesn't match which would exclude the so your Claim ID, Provider ID and Member ID would ALL have to match to get a record.

Your WHERE clause could be re-written like:

```
WHERE
     dh.document_id LIKE '%'+@ClaimID+'%'
     AND (xfi.FOLDER_TYPE_ID = '19' AND xfi.folder_id LIKE '%'+@MemberID+'%')
     AND (RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300' AND LEFT(xfi.folder_id, LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5) LIKE '%'+@ProviderID+'%')
```

You also don't have any parenthesis so when you do change the first AND to an OR, it looks for the Doc ID that has the Claim ID parameter OR all the other conditions.

I think you want this WHERE clause but with OR instead of AND with the parenthesis to keep the different conditions together (i.e. TYPE_ID = 19 **AND** Folder ID = Member ID).

```
WHERE
     dh.document_id LIKE '%'+@ClaimID+'%'
     OR (xfi.FOLDER_TYPE_ID = '19' AND xfi.folder_id LIKE '%'+@MemberID+'%')
     OR (RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300' AND LEFT(xfi.folder_id, LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5) LIKE '%'+@ProviderID+'%')
```